# Make a field required in lwc form

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I have created a lightning web component, which takes in two values LastName and Email and creates a Contact record.

Here I have made the LastName as required

**html code**

```
<template>
 <form>
    <lightning-input type = "text" 
                    label = "LastName" 
                    onchange = {handleLastNameChange}
                    required>
    </lightning-input>  
    <lightning-input type = "text" 
                    label = "Email" 
                    onchange = {handleEmailChange}>
    </lightning-input> 
    <lightning-button label = "Create Contact" onclick = "{createContact}"
                      class="slds-m-top_medium"></lightning-button>
  </form>
 </template>
```

Now in my **JS file**, I have createContactRecord method which saves the Contact Record by calling an Apex class

```
    createContact(){
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
        element.reportValidity();
    });
    createContactRecord ({con : this.contactRecord})
    .then(result => {  

            /*Other JS Logic*/  
      
            this.template.querySelector('form').reset();
        }
    )
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error.message;
    })
   }
```

Now, my issue here is that, once the component loads the first time, and I try clicking on Create Contact button, it gives me the mandatory validation perfectly.

However, if I have saved the first Contact record and

```
 this.template.querySelector('form').reset();
```

has reset the values of the entire form.

The next time I click on Create Contact button without entering LastName, the required validation does not show up, anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you can follow below approach:-

Assign a name attribute in your input field and use it to filter the accessed input field while resetting the value:-

```
<lightning-input type = "text" 
                label = "LastName"
                required name="LastName">
</lightning-input>
```

Then use **querySelectorAll** to access all the input field and filter the field based on name attribute and assign the value of it as defined.

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input').forEach(element => {
     if(element.name === 'LastName'){
        element.value = undefined;
     }            
});
```

Basically, When you use `this.template.querySelector('form').reset();` it does not reset the value of the input field in value attribute. It just clears the form value on the UI. Hence validation does not work next time.

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful!!!